# how to multiple A column from table A by B column in table B in a pandas dataframe join?

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, pandas

The environment is

```
Python version 2.7.11
Pandas version 0.18.1
```

Assume we have the following input tables A & B:

A

```
ID,FROM_YEAR,TYPE,AREA1,AREA2
1,2015,A,100,200
1,2015,B,100,200
```

B

```
ID,FROM_YEAR,TYPE,COEFFICIENT
1,2015,A,100,1.5
1,2015,B,100,2.0
```

Ideal output:

```
ID,FROM_YEAR,TYPE,AREA1,AREA2
1,2015,A,100,**300**
1,2015,B,100,**400**
```

where 200*1.5 = 300 & 200*2.0=400

The MySQL query is:

```
SELECT 
a.ID,
a.FROM_YEAR,
a.TYPE,
a.AREA1,
a.AREA2*b.COEFFICIENT AS AREA2
FROM a
INNER JOIN b
ON 
a.ID=b.ID, 
a.FROM_YEAR=b.FROM_YEAR,
a.TYPE=b.TYPE
```

Is it possible to do this in Python pandas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [eval()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html#expression-evaluation-via-eval-experimental) method:

```
In [11]: pd.merge(A, B, on=['ID','FROM_YEAR','TYPE']) \
           .eval('AREA2 = AREA2 * COEFFICIENT', inplace=False)
Out[11]:
   ID  FROM_YEAR TYPE  AREA1_x  AREA2  AREA1_y  COEFFICIENT
0   1       2015    A      100  300.0      100          1.5
1   1       2015    B      100  400.0      100          2.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would you mind to explain a little bit about the eval function here?

Comment: @Chubaka, i've added a link to Pandas docs, where you can find many examples - i don't think i can explain it better ;)